# Matplotlib Not Working on Mac

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm running Python 2.7.14 on macOS High Sierra, and when I run my matplotlib script, the plot doesn't show up, and the script hangs. I've tried editing my `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` file multiple times, trying lots of backends, as other answers have suggested, but the problem persists.

Please help.

Comment: which version of matplotlib do you have?

Comment: @tom Version 2.1.0

Comment: There are some known issues with v2.1.0 on the mac (e.g. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9489) which should be fixed by v2.1.1. Not sure if that's relevant in this case (since you don't see the same error message). You could try installing the master or v2.1.x branch from github to see if that solves the issue (it solved the above issue for me). Alternatively, you could try rolling back (e.g. to 2.0.2) to see if that helps.

Comment: Also, have you tried just opening a python session and importing matplotlib? Does that work ok? If so, can you create a simple plot and display it?

Comment: @tom Yes, importing works, but I'm unable to display even a simple plot. How do I install it from master?

Comment: see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib

Comment: As python begins to interact with the GUI it will spawn an icon with a bouncing python rocket. Do you see that appear in your taskbar at all?

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone Exactly! I see it forever bouncing! But I never see the plot. The rocket doesn't launch.

Comment: Check out your syslog while you try and open a plot. Open a terminal and type tail -f /var/log/system.log . It may provide clues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution was to use a different backend in cases I used wxPython GUI.

```
matplotlib.use('WxAgg')
```

of you might need to add a line plt.show(block = True) if you want to just plot a graph.

See here for a very similar problem.
[Matplotlib fails and hangs when plotting in interactive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490426/matplotlib-fails-and-hangs-when-plotting-in-interactive-mode)