# Matplotlib fails and hangs when plotting in interactive mode

Tags: macos, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am getting a problem with my matplotlib library on MacOS High Sierra.

- matplotlib-2.2.2
- python 2.7.14

Here is my super simple code.

```
plt.ion()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The python symbol appears on the dash board but the window cannot be found anywhere.

if I don't use ion() I can get one plot at a time.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plt.ion()` seems to be bugged. Try the following workaround:

```
plt.ion()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.pause(0.0001)
plt.show()
```

If this still does not work, try replacing the last line with:

```
plt.show(block=True)
```

Comment: The part that made it work was addition of plt.show(block = True)